# Unable to connect smoldot to our chain

Tags: light-client

Running the example on https://github.com/paritytech/smoldot and I added our chainspec in `bin/` and also added an entry here: https://github.com/paritytech/smoldot/blob/dd27ec825145f75b67ca6bd1d737dc7d7bf03fad/bin/wasm-node/javascript/demo/demo.mjs#L36

I get the following output when trying to connect to our chain over the websocket served by the example:

```
[16:03:59.568] [smoldot] Chain initialization complete for tfchain_devnet. Name: "TF Chain Devnet". Genesis hash: 0xbb7f…66be. State root hash: 0x6a2e10fffcd6d5ffb97ad5a52d89a9cd9681fc6ce59cd4cc9780d201b1b54030. Network identity: 12D3KooWMFHBBUN6X97XJeSHLiBDuXPJcroC329S9RJgmTbovvL4. Chain specification or database starting at: 0xbb7f…66be (#0)
[16:03:59.570] [json-rpc-tfchain_devnet] The JSON-RPC client has just called a JSON-RPC function from the legacy JSON-RPC API (chain_getBlockHash). Legacy JSON-RPC functions have loose semantics and cannot be properly implemented on a light client. You are encouraged to use the new JSON-RPC API <https://github.com/paritytech/json-rpc-interface-spec/> instead. The legacy JSON-RPC API functions will be deprecated and removed in the distant future.
[16:04:09.568] [sync-service-tfchain_devnet] GrandPa warp sync idle
[16:04:09.664] [runtime-tfchain_devnet] Successfully compiled runtime. Spec version: 49. Size of `:code`: 906 kiB.
[16:04:18.921] [smoldot] Smoldot v0.7.8. Current memory usage: 157 MiB. Average download: 2.7 MiB/s. Average upload: 6.2 kiB/s.
[16:04:19.568] [sync-service-tfchain_devnet] GrandPa warp sync idle
[16:04:29.568] [sync-service-tfchain_devnet] GrandPa warp sync idle
[16:04:39.568] [sync-service-tfchain_devnet] GrandPa warp sync idle
```

Comment: Could you provide your chainspec?

Comment: https://github.com/threefoldtech/tfchain/blob/development/substrate-node/chainspecs/main/chainSpecRaw.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the ChainSpec you provided, I can see that there are no bootnodes set, for `substrate-connect` to connnect to. E.g. if you see the `westend` chainspec provided in substrate-connect repository [there are some bootnodes added there](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-connect/blob/main/packages/connect/src/connector/specs/westend2.json#L4-L15).

In order to make your collator listening for WebSocket connections add `--listen-addr /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30334/ws --listen-addr /ip6/::/tcp/30334/ws`. Highlighting the `/ws` at the end, the `IP` and `port` can be modified and aren't important)

Why is it necessary and what it does? Browsers only allow webpages to open WebSocket connections, meaning that the node you want to connect to needs to listen for WebSocket connections.

In addition it should have an `HTTP reverse-proxy` in front of the node (e.g. `nginx`, but could be something else), connected to the corresponding port (e.g. `30333` above), and with an SSL certificate configured. The domain name of this SSL certificate isn't really important. You will need to have an SSL certificate in order to go around browsers' security measures.

Comment: Right, I also tried with another chainspec that has bootnodes: https://github.com/threefoldtech/tfchain/blob/development/substrate-node/chainspecs/dev/chainSpecRaw.json but it gave me the same result.

Comment: The bootnodes in that chainspec are missing the `ws` bootnodes. If you see the link of `westend` spec mentioned above there are 2 types. The `p2p` and the `ws`. If you have the collator listening to websocket connections and, you can try by duplicating the ones and add the `ws` part.

Comment: Seems to be working with the latest version of smoldot and adding a ws bootnode. Thanks for the help!